# how to assign external php file string to a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, http-headers

I'm trying to read data from external php file using ajax, then I want to assign this data to a javascript variable. I want to check if my code is ok like that or should I define the variable inside the ajax brackets.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/mydata.php',
  success: function(data) { alert(data); }  
   });

 var foo = data;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do this, you need to define `foo` out of ajax request for use on another ctx:

```
var foo;    
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/mydata.php',
  success: function(data) { 
    alert(data);
    foo = data; 
    }  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the value to your variable inside the `success` callback (where `data` exists) as follows:

```
var foo;

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/mydata.php',
  success: function(data) {
    var bar = data; // works
    foo = data;     // works too
  }
});
```